# Add Defer Attributes to WordPress Scripts with consistent versioning

Tags: filters, wp-enqueue-script

I want to use the defer attribute for scripts. I understand this can be done using `script_loader_tag`. However I also want consistent versioning of the files as some plugins do not do it properly.

How do I find scripts' versioning when I use

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', …
```

using their handles?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$wp_scripts`, which is a `global` variable to get the version of a registered script.

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'script_handler', 10, 3 );
function script_handler( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
  // the following global contains all the information you need
  global $wp_scripts;
  $ver = $wp_scripts->registered[ $handle ]->ver;

  // do your thing
}
```

Note, this is exemplary.

Comment: Thanks. 

Doesn't this need "for each"?

Also my problem is that some plugins don't register the correct version in wp_enqueue_scripts, so will  this recover the correct version?

Comment: @Ramanan No, it doesn't need a `for each`, `$handle` is a `string`. `script_loader_tag` applies to every script separately. This will recover the version the script is registered with, so no. Unless you know exactly where the correct version is saved I see no possibility to retrieve it, because WordPress doesn't know anything about the actual version, it knows just the one given to it when registering the script.

Comment: Thanks again. Can't I use get_plugin_data?

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugin_data. It seems to take the filepath as input. 

My basic problem is: get all the scripts in any page, add the defer attribute and version them correctly.

Comment: @Ramanan Sure, you can use `get_plugin_data`. I assumed you want the version of the script of the javascript file you're loading.